# UISwitch display another text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

Why in StoryBoard UIswitch show me text like `ON/OFF`, and when I use app in simulator I see wrong text `|`

In .plist I have "Localization native development region" equal "en"

[image]

Comment: `UISwitch` uses the system's language settings (as set by the user). What do you want it to show?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460526/uiswitch-0-1-to-on-off) tells that it depends on the device settings not on the plist values